# Error from equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, errors

Below is a MWE. While the pdf output seems ok, TeXniccenter displays error in the equation line. Not able to understand what's wrong. Happens even when I put in the code to close the curly brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
$\mu(S_{QX})=N$ where $S_{QX}=\left\{c\in N \lvert $U_{c}(X) > U_{c}(Q)$\} $ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We don't usually start questions with a greeting, so I've edited the question slightly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Braces which opened by `\left` must be closed with `\right` in the same math-part/line.

The next problem is the underscore. It is only available in mathmode.

To avoid combination with `left/right` you can influence the size via `\big` or `\bigg` etc. For more details see [mathmode](http://ctan.mackichan.com/help/Catalogue/entries/voss-mathmode.html) by Herbert Voß.

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
$\mu(S_{QX})=N$ where $S_{QX}=\left\{c\in N \lvert U_{c}(X) > U_{c}(Q)\right\} $ 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Marco, the math mode link is extremely useful :-).